# Extend component with composition API in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

With options API we can use these ways to extend components. Let's say we've 2 components.

Component1.vue

```html
<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    init(message) {
      alert(message)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Component2.vue

```html
<script>
    import Component1 from './Component1'
    
    export default {
      extends: Component1,
      methods: {
        showAlert() {
          // we can access Component1 'init()' method here
          this.init('Hello World!')
        }
      },
      mounted() {
        this.showAlert()
      }
    }
</script>
```

Now, how to make it work with composition API? I've checked that `extends` property still available at the documentation but there's no clear usage explanation about that.

https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-composition.html#extends

Consider the following code with composition API.

Component1.vue

```html
<script>
import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  setup () {
    const init = (message) => {
      alert(message)
    }
    
    return {
      init
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

Component2.vue

```html
<script>
import { defineComponent, ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
import Component1 from './Component1.vue'

export default defineComponent({
  extends: Component1,
  setup () {
    const showAlert = () => {
      // How to access 'init()' method here?
    }
    
    onMounted(() => {
      showAlert()
    })
  }
})
</script>
```

Thank you!

Comment: did you fix it? I think the answer was reuse the function, not reuse the component. I am facing the same problem as you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70866392/how-to-return-a-public-component-in-vue-3 @Muhammad Rizki A.  I want to nest the public component into the parent.

Comment: what's closest to it is the extends option that you can use in `defineComponent`. See https://vuejs.org/api/options-composition.html#extends a "base class" component to extend from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Composition api enforces the code reusability with composable function which could be used across multiple components, so create a file named `useInit.js` with following content :

```js
const useInit=()=>{
     const init = (message) => {
      alert(message)
    }
    
    return {
      init
    }
}

export default useInit;
```

then import it in every component like:

**component 1**

```html
<script>
import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue'
import useInit from './useInit'
export default defineComponent({
  setup () {
    const {init} = useInit()
    
    return {
      init
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

**Component 2**

```html
<script>
import { defineComponent, ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
import Component1 from './Component1.vue'
import useInit from './useInit'

export default defineComponent({

  setup () {
     const {init} = useInit()
     const showAlert = () => {
       init()
     }
    
    onMounted(() => {
      showAlert()
    })
  }
})
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I think it could be a good way to achieve this.

However, I'm still curious about how to accomplish this with `extends` property. Why it still on the documentation and how to use that with composition API?

Please check this documentation link:
https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-composition.html#extends

Comment: In vue 3 you could use options and composition api in the same component, but you shouldn't interchange properties/methods between the options and the setup hook, and since `extend` is an option (belongs to options api) it doesn't get access to setup hook.

Comment: the syntax used in vue 2 is valid in version 3

Comment: Okay that's pretty clear and make sense to me. So in other words, there's no 'extends' feature if we choose to use composition API, right?

Comment: Yes, `extends` is used only for option api to make components reusable, for composition api there's a different approach by using composable functions which could be used in different components.

Comment: This approach is much more verbose than extends and requires you to redefine all props from the base component. The issue here is mainly just that the docs are totally lacking in explaining what happens if you extend a component built with composition API

Comment: There is no valid reason that composition abrogates inheritance even in a so-called "composition" API. They are simply design patterns a user can and should use at will. The design patterns are not add odds with each other and doesn't necessitate I use one over the other.  While the Composition API "suggests" the composition design, it shouldn't "demand" I exclusively use it. If fact, there is a huge body of work that use both together. Then, use the Option API? Why, when I should be able to extend one composable object from another without issue.

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party but check this:

https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0009-global-api-change.md#global-api-mapping

```js
export default defineComponent({ extends: defineComponent({ ... }) });
```

Also this https://github.com/pearofducks/mount-vue-component

Comment: This seems to be part of `LegacyOptions` interface, I wonder what's non-legacy option?...

Comment: I checked it again and looks like it only inherits the component options. So technically, you can't do this now with Composition API as it suggests composition instead of inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Its really pretty straight forward, here is my code that works great:

BaseComponent.vue

```
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
 export default defineComponent({
        methods: {
...
        },
})
```

ChildComponent.vue

```
    import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
    import BaseComponent from '@/components/BaseComponent.vue'
     export default defineComponent({
     extends: BaseComponent, 
    
...
    
    })
```